# New sharing option named "DEV" added to the "share" option

Tags: support, sharing, share-this

In Stack Overflow, when clicking on the "share" option on a post, in the "share" popup, there is a new icon added as "DEV", clicking on that navigates to [https://dev.to](https://dev.to/).

Is the "DEV" sharing option added newly? If it is intentionality added, will the option be added for Code Review, GIS, Salesforce, Android Enthusiasts and other development-related communities too?

> [image: Share - DEV option]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, if folks use the DEV sharing option on Stack Overflow, we'll consider adding it on other appropriate SE sites, too. In the meantime, you can still add embeds from any Stack Exchange site to posts on DEV now. [You can read about how to use this new feature here](https://dev.to/devteam/changelog-stack-overflow-liquid-tag-12o2). If you're not familiar with DEV, it's a site for programmers to create, find, and share articles, discussions, etc.

So if you have a cool story behind any Stack Exchange question or answer that you'd like to elaborate on in a blog-style post, DEV is a good place to share! If you create any posts on DEV that use Stack Exchange embeds, reply in the comments here--I'd love to read and share!

Comment: Is Stack Overflow affiliated in any way with DEV the company? If not, what triggered  this change?

Comment: No, we are not. They had wanted to add a Stack Exchange embed for a while. We gave them a hand https://github.com/thepracticaldev/dev.to/issues/1419 and also decided to try this out, too.

Comment: Bit of a silly side question but... what *is* DEV?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Point your browser to https://dev.to/about. :)

Comment: I can't even figure out how to use it...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek a blog platform (think Medium copycat) branded for developer. Nothing fancy.

Comment: @aloisdg And, like Medium, it seems to be flooded with mostly terrible content, which in turn gets spammed elsewhere. I had high hopes for the platform but I’m currently sceptical.